# Call python module from within bash script

Tags: python, bash, module

My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=abc
MYIP=xyz
python3.5 -m webbrowser http://myserver/script.php?host=$HOSTNAME&ip=$MYIP
```

Unfortunately when I run that script it will not terminate.
Any idea why this does not work properly?

Comment: This works fine for me: `web.sh` is `HOSTNAME=example;EXT=com;python -m webbrowser http://$HOSTNAME.$EXT`. In the terminal `$ ./web.sh` opens the webbrowser at the correct site and the script terminates.  What happens if you do `./web.sh &`?

Comment: quote your entire url.. you have a raw '&'.. so double quote it..

Comment: I am running this on a dietpi based raspberry. So there is no browser that can be opened. I think that is the issue why the script will not terminate.
My intent is to call a PHP script from my server from within my bash script. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: curl is my friend... that seems to work perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

In linux bash: '&' is a command terminator. If you want to use '&' then place your URL inside single or double quote.

Example:

```
python3.5 -m webbrowser "http://myserver/script.php?host=$HOSTNAME&ip=$MYIP"
```

Else, manually kill your script every time using CTRL+C or CTRL+Z